# How to select lists with the same id in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-preprocessing

I have a dataframe that look like this:

| id | place | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 13 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 13 | 4 | 4 | 2 |
| 14 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 14 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 14 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

I want to select `place`, `age` and `gender` where `id` is unique in Python. For example for `id=13`, I want to select the matrix:

| place | age | gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 2 |

Notice that the ids doesn't have the same length.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the rows which have the `id` as 13 by doing just `df[df['id'] == 13]`.

And if you only want the remaining columns `place`, `age` and `gender`, then:

```py
df.loc[df['id'] == 13, ['place', 'age', 'gender']]
# or
df[df['id'] == 13][['place', 'age', 'gender']]
```

Comment: god I love this syntax `df[df['id'] == 13][['place', 'age', 'gender']]`...

Comment: @HamzaMks In your for-loop, change `df[:,'id']` to `df.loc[:,'id']`. Or just `for i in df['id']:` if you only want the id's individually in the loop.